# Using configSource with NWebsec

Tags: asp.net, web-config, nwebsec

In an attempt to simplify our `web.config`, I wanted to break out the NWebsec configuration into a separate file using the `configSource` attribute:

### `web.config`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="nwebsec">
      <section name="httpHeaderSecurityModule" type="NWebsec.Modules.Configuration.HttpHeaderSecurityConfigurationSection, NWebsec, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3613da5f958908a1" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <nwebsec configSource="App_Config\NWebsec.config" />
  <!--- remainder of file omitted for brevity -->
</configuration>
```

### `App_Config\NWebsec.config`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<nwebsec>
  <httpHeaderSecurityModule xmlns="http://nwebsec.com/HttpHeaderSecurityModuleConfig.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <redirectValidation enabled="true">
      <!-- omitted for brevity -->
    </redirectValidation>
    <securityHttpHeaders>
      <!-- omitted for brevity -->
    </securityHttpHeaders>
  </httpHeaderSecurityModule>
</nwebsec>
```

When I make a request to the application I now receive a HTTP 500 error with no other details. There is also nothing related in the Windows Event Viewer.

Is what I'm attempting possible with NWebsec configuration?

How do I get more detail on the error which is occurring and causing the HTTP 500 response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is because the `nwebsec` element is defined as a `sectionGroup`:

```
<sectionGroup name="nwebsec">
  <section name="httpHeaderSecurityModule" type="..." />
</sectionGroup>
```

The `configSource` attribute works for the `section` element only.

Amending the `web.config`:

```
<nwebsec>
  <httpHeaderSecurityModule configSource="App_Config\NWebsec.config" />
</nwebsec>
```

In addition to amending the root element of the referenced file (`App_Config\NWebsec.config`), enables this to work as desired:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<httpHeaderSecurityModule xmlns="http://nwebsec.com/HttpHeaderSecurityModuleConfig.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <redirectValidation enabled="true">
  ...
```