# Same configuration for NWebSec in old ASP.NET project and in a .NET Core subproject

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, content-security-policy, nwebsec

In our "vintage" ASP.NET project we configured NWebSec through the web.config file. Now we have a ASP.NET Core subproject where the NWebSec rules from the main project don't seem to bubble down. 
Also I could not really figure out how to configure NWebSec in a Core project besides using Attributes.

https://docs.nwebsec.com/en/latest/nwebsec/Configuring-csp.html

What I really want is one central place to do the configuration, otherwise I know we will end up with two completely out of sync configs...

I'm not yet a .NET Core expert, but my impression was that the web.config file is not used anymore, otherwise we could do something like that:
[Using configSource with NWebsec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53342371/using-configsource-with-nwebsec)

Comment: `What I really want is one central place to do the configuration` You can try to install [NWebsec.AspNetCore.Middleware](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NWebsec.AspNetCore.Middleware/) and configure CSP middleware to achieve it.

Comment: Thanks. But that Middleware only seems to work for .NET Core, no?