# How to use xdt-transform when the Web.config element already contains a different xmlns

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, web-config-transform, xdt-transform

Using Visual Studio Web.Config Transforms, I want to include the following line in Web.Debug.Config: `<add source="*.amazonaws.com" />`

This is my Web.config

```
<configuration>
  <!--
    -- More config here
  -->
  <nwebsec>
    <httpHeaderSecurityModule xmlns="http://nwebsec.com/HttpHeaderSecurityModuleConfig.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="NWebsecConfig/HttpHeaderSecurityModuleConfig.xsd">
      <securityHttpHeaders>
        <content-Security-Policy enabled="true">
          <default-src none="true" />
          <script-src self="true" unsafeEval="true">
            <add source="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com"/>
          </script-src>
          <style-src unsafeInline="true" self="true">
            <add source="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com"/>
          </style-src>
          <img-src self="true">
            <add source="data:" />
            <add source="*.w3.org"/>
            <!-- ******** I want to insert new source here for Dev ******** -->
          </img-src>
          <object-src none="true" />
          <media-src none="true" />
          <frame-ancestors none="true" />
          <report-uri enableBuiltinHandler="true"/>
        </content-Security-Policy>
      </securityHttpHeaders>
    </httpHeaderSecurityModule>
  </nwebsec>
</configuration>
```

I have done what is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5732681/is-there-any-way-to-do-a-replace-or-insert-using-web-config-transformation), in Web.Debug.config:

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <system.web></system.web>
  <nwebsec>
    <httpHeaderSecurityModule> <!-- I have remove xmlns=... from this element -->
      <securityHttpHeaders>
        <content-Security-Policy enabled="true">
          <img-src self="true" xdt:Transform="Remove" />
          <img-src self="true" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
            <add source="data:" />
            <add source="*.w3.org"/>
            <add source="*.amazonaws.com" />
          </connect-src>
        </content-Security-Policy>
      </securityHttpHeaders>
    </httpHeaderSecurityModule>
  </nwebsec>
</configuration>
```

But the new line is not added, how can I do this?

I think this is because `httpHeaderSecurityModule` has `xmlns` attribute but don't know how to solve this issue?

Note that I have removed the `xmlns=...` from `httpHeaderSecurityModule` in the transform file, if I include the namespace I get the following syntax error:

> The 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform:Transform'
> attribute is not declared

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if there is a better solution but I could not get the transforms working inside `httpHeaderSecurityModule` (which has `xmlns=...`) element, according to [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dd465326(v=vs.110)):

> The root element of a transform file must specify the
> XML-Document-Transform namespace in its opening tag

The only way that I could do this transform was to replace everything above the element which has `xmlns`, i.e.

```
  <nwebsec xdt:Transform="Remove" />
  <nwebsec xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
    <httpHeaderSecurityModule xmlns="http://nwebsec.com/HttpHeaderSecurityModuleConfig.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="NWebsecConfig/HttpHeaderSecurityModuleConfig.xsd">
      <securityHttpHeaders>
        <content-Security-Policy enabled="true">
          <default-src none="true" />
          <script-src self="true" unsafeEval="true">
            <add source="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com"/>
          </script-src>
          <style-src unsafeInline="true" self="true">
            <add source="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com"/>
          </style-src>
          <img-src self="true">
            <add source="data:" />
            <add source="*.w3.org"/>
            <!-- ******** I want to insert new source here for Dev ******** -->
          </img-src>
          <object-src none="true" />
          <media-src none="true" />
          <frame-ancestors none="true" />
          <report-uri enableBuiltinHandler="true"/>
        </content-Security-Policy>
      </securityHttpHeaders>
    </httpHeaderSecurityModule>
  </nwebsec>
```

Answer (score 0):

One alternative could be to use a separate config file instead of a full transformation. You can do something like this:

```
<nwebsec xdt:Transform="Remove" />
  <nwebsec xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
  <httpHeaderSecurityModule configSource="NWebsec.config" >
  </httpHeaderSecurityModule>
</nwebsec>
```

Unfortunately you cannot directly use the nwebsec elemente ([see here why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53342371/using-configsource-with-nwebsec)).